# Can i get all rows from a table on SQL and count them in same function or query?

Tags: sql, isqlquery

so can i do both queries from getAllProduktet ?

```
   function getAllProduktet($kataloguID)
  {
$query = "SELECT produktet.ID, Pershkrimi, Qmimi,Fotografia, TVSH, Katalogu   from      produktet, tvsh, katalogu "
." where produktet.tvshID = tvsh.ID and produktet.kataloguID = katalogu.ID "
." and Statusi = 1";
if($kataloguID != "0")
    $query .= " and kataloguID = {$kataloguID}";

   global $lidhja;
$rezultati = mysql_query($query, $lidhja);
if(!$rezultati)
    die(" Gabim ".mysql_error());
return $rezultati;
    }
```

and the other query that does this

```
$query_banner = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produktet ORDER BY ID  LIMIT     $from,$max_show") or die(mysql_error());
while($show=mysql_fetch_array($query_banner))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mysql_num_rows in php or count(field) in the query